# golang type array containing structs

Tags: go

I am trying to create a pseudo queue structure and insert jobs structs inside it. What am I doing wrong ?

```
import "fmt"

type Job struct {
    Type string
    Url string
}

type Queue [] Job

func main() {
    var queue []Queue
    job   := Job{"test", "http://google.com"}

    queue[0] = job
    fmt.Println(queue)
}
```

The code above is throwing:

> cannot use job (type Job) as type Queue in assignment

Comment: remove the `[]` in `var queue []Queue`, you'll still get runtime error though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think problem is here:

```
var queue []Queue
```

Here `queue` is a slice of `Queue` or slice of slice of `Job`. So it's impossible to assign first its element value of `Job`.

Try:

```
var queue Queue
```

Comment: You are right, but now it's throwing: panic: runtime error: index out of range . I added queue = append(queue, job) and it's now working with the above modification. Thank you.

Comment: @TheodorB, quite right, because `queue` was just created and has no zeroth element. Using `append` add such element. Have you checked `len` and `cap` functions for slice?

Comment: Not yet but I will have a look. Thank you once again for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a slice of queues, and you should not index an empty slice.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Job struct {
    Type string
    Url string
}

type Queue []Job

func main() {
    var q Queue
    job := Job{"test", "http://google.com"}
    q = append(q, job)
    fmt.Println(q)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[]TypeName` is definition of slice of `TypeName` type.

Just as it said:

`var queue []Queue` is a slice of instances of type `Queue`.

```
q := Queue{Job{"test", "http://google.com"}, Job{"test", "http://google.com"}}
```

Definitely it is not what you want. Instead of it you should declare `var queue Queue`:

```
var queue Queue
q := append(queue, Job{"test", "http://google.com"}, Job{"test", "http://google.com"})
```